How to set view target to a specific camera component
I've been trying to migrate spring arm and camera components from my pawn to my player controller class. Unfortunately, it seems like the controller class already has a Camera member variable, and when I use SetViewTarget(this), the player views in the positive x direction from the player controller's TransformComponent location instead of from the camera component I added. I am simply looking for a way to set the camera the player views from using a reference to my camera component, instead of having the controller use the first camera it finds in an actor.
